# Compact convergence of bivariate complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $b_n\in H(D(0,R))$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on a disc of radius $R$ centered at $0$, $\Omega=D(0,R)\times D(0,S)$, $|w_0|<S$.
Take a compactly convergent (that is, uniformly convergent on every compact $K\in\Omega$) series $$f(z,w)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z)(w-w_0)^n.$$
In $\Omega$ we can also write $$f(z,w)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n(z)w^n$$ for some $a_n\in H(D(0,R))$.
This series is (absolutely) convergent on $\Omega$, because the first one is, but is it compactly convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the first statement, the $f(z,w)$ is holomorphic.  The functions $a_n$ are uniquely determined by $f$: it is $\frac{1}{n!} \frac{\partial^n f}{\partial w^n}(z,0)$.  The function $f$ has a power series that converges absolutely uniformly on compact subsets
$$
f(z,w) = \sum_{j,k} c_{j,k} z^jw^k
$$
Now that means we can group the terms in any way we want, including as
$$
f(z,w) = \sum_{k} \left( \sum_j c_{j,k} z^j \right) w^k
$$
The limit is uniform here if it was uniform above (that is not hard to show).  The sum in the parentheses is your $a_k(z)$ since that was the unique function there.

Comment: How do I show the second limit is uniform?

Comment: And I don't know if you made a typo, or if I misunderstand, the coefficients in the first line should be $b_n$ and not $a_n$, and they should equal to $b_n=\frac1{n!}\frac{\partial^nf}{\partial w^n}(z,w_0)$, because the series is centered at $w_0$, right?

Comment: No, no typo (at least I can't see one).  I expanded the series of $f$ at the origin as a Taylor series irregardless of the form you gave.  So that's why I used a new letter, $c_{jk}$.  The idea is not to use the series you start with except to show that $f$ is holomorphic in the polydisc (and for that you just use that it is a uniform limit on compact subsets of holomorphic functions ... the partial sums of that series with $b_n$'s).   Then you forget about the $b_n$'s and that series completely.  ... (continued)

Comment: You expand the function $f$ in its Taylor series to identify candidates for the $a_n$'s as certain "subsums" in the Taylor series.  Then you find that they are unique, so that no matter how I arrive at the $a_n$'s I have the same $a_n$'s because they just depend on the values of $f$.  $b_n$'s are not at all used in the argument.  Then I use the fact that the Taylor series is known to converge uniformly absolutely on compact subsets of the polydisc to show that the series with the $a_n$'s converges so.